# Vba: Como alinhar a esquerda uma seleção de células enviadas no outlook como html?

Tags: html, vba, excel-vba, outlook

Vou suprimir partes do código para facilitar a visualização do problema:

```
Dim objSelection As Excel.Range
Dim objTempWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objTempWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strTempHTMLFile As String
Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim objOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim usuario As String
Dim linhaemail As Long

'Copia a seleção de uma sheet que será enviada no e-mail'

Sheets("Padrão E-mail").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:K29").Select
Set objSelection = Selection
Selection.Copy

'Cola a range em uma pasta de trabalho temporária'
Set objTempWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Mantem os valores e formatação durante a colagem'
 With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
 End With

'Salva a worksheet temporária como hmtl'
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & "\Temp for Excel" & 
Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, 
strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)
Set objTextStream = objFileSystem.OpenTextFile(strTempHTMLFile)

'Cria um novo e-mail'
Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNewEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Le o arquivo HTML e insere no corpo do e-mail'
 objNewEmail.HTMLBody = objTextStream.ReadAll
```

Quando essa seleção de células (salvas em um arquivo temporário como html) vai para o outlook, ele a reconhece como uma tabela, e por padrão, estas vêm alinhadas ao centro, e fico com esse espaço em branco na esquerda. Conforme a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como poderia colocar o alinhamento a esquerda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

```
 objNewEmail.HTMLBody = "<table align=""left"">" & objTextStream.ReadAll & "</table>" & "<p align=""left"">" & objNewEmail.HTMLBody & "</p>"
```

Comment: Favor marcar depois como respondido.